# SweetAlert2 implementation in cakephp4

Tags: cakephp, sweetalert2

does anyone have a link with information to implement sweetalert2 with cakephp 4?

I've been trying since yesterday and haven't achieved anything yet.

Comment: SweetAlert2 is a standalone js library & it has nothing to do with cakephp. How did you install it? What have you tried so far? Output and expected behavior, please include all those information to get helpful answers.

Comment: I want to change the message displayed by postLink to delete records in cakephp4

Comment: Didn't understand your problem quite. Please attach relevant codes.

Comment: You can see e.g. [here](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/table) that it is easy and possible to replace the helper button code for post links and create your own logic/HTML/JS instead. You just need to code it, and put it in a plugin for example.